# Get value of TypedMap from Constraints.ValidationPayload

Tags: java, validation, playframework

We're using playframework 2.8 with java and have implemented a form validation using DI and a payload as explained in the official play documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaForms#Custom-class-level-constraints-with-DI-support

The payload object provides a **TypedMap** containing attributes from the request, using the *getAttr()* method. This is explained by [this documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/api/java/play/data/validation/Constraints.ValidationPayload.html#getAttrs--)

Since the instance of a **TypedKey** is used to store the value in the map, we're not able to access any request attributes, stored by the framework itself. More details can be found on [Github](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7707) and in [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61639712/play-framework-validatewithpayload)

It seems, it's not possible to fetch all existing keys from a TypedMap.
**So, the question is:** How can we get values of the TypedMap, which were already stored by play, when we don't have the instance of the TypedKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys for `Request.attrs` TypedMap are stored inside `play.api.mvc.request.RequestAttrKey` object:

```scala
package play.api.mvc.request

import ...

/**
 * Keys to request attributes.
 */
object RequestAttrKey {

  /**
   * The key for the request attribute storing a request id.
   */
  val Id = TypedKey[Long]("Id")

  /**
   * The key for the request attribute storing a [[Cell]] with
   * [[play.api.mvc.Cookies]] in it.
   */
  val Cookies = TypedKey[Cell[Cookies]]("Cookies")

  /**
   * The key for the request attribute storing a [[Cell]] with
   * the [[play.api.mvc.Session]] cookie in it.
   */
  val Session = TypedKey[Cell[Session]]("Session")

  /**
   * The key for the request attribute storing a [[Cell]] with
   * the [[play.api.mvc.Flash]] cookie in it.
   */
  val Flash = TypedKey[Cell[Flash]]("Flash")

  /**
   * The key for the request attribute storing the server name.
   */
  val Server = TypedKey[String]("Server-Name")

  /**
   * The CSP nonce key.
   */
  val CSPNonce: TypedKey[String] = TypedKey("CSP-Nonce")
}
```

Those are scala keys. This is not big problem, java TypedMap is just wrapper for scala TypedMap.

Example usage from java, when we have Http.Request:

```java
import scala.compat.java8.OptionConverters;
import play.api.mvc.request.RequestAttrKey;

class SomeController extends Controller {

    public Result index(Http.Request request) {

        //get request attrs  
        play.libs.typedmap.TypedMap javaAttrs = request.attrs();

        //get underlying scala TypedMap
        play.api.libs.typedmap.TypedMap attrs = javaAttrs.asScala();

        //e.g. get Session from scala attrs
        Optional<Cell<Session>> session = 
            OptionConverters.toJava(attrs.get(RequestAttrKey.Session()));

        //process session data
        session.ifPresent(sessionCell -> {
            Map<String, String> sessionsData = sessionCell.value().asJava().data();

        //do something with session data
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: in our case `javaAttrs.get(RequestAttrKey.Session().asJava())` is sufficient